# Firebase Remote Config throws fetch status 0 exception when user offline on Unity Editor

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

In my gaming Unity ( 2021.3.2f1 version) project, I'm using remote config SDK ( 9.5.0)  for finetuning the game data. Players can play on offline mode, in order to do that I'm setting default values of each config key from json local path. Below code shows the implementation of config method. SetupRemoteConfig() is called when the firebase app is initiliazed.

```
public void SetupRemoteConfig()
{
    var remoteConfig = FirebaseRemoteConfig.DefaultInstance;

    Dictionary<string, object> configDefaults = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    configDefaults.Add(ConfigKeys.adjust_testMode.ToString(), true);
    configDefaults.Add(ConfigKeys.ShopPageCoinPackConfigs.ToString(), GetDefaultJsonString(ConfigKeys.ShopPageCoinPackConfigs));

    var configSettings = new ConfigSettings();

    if (Debug.isDebugBuild)
    {
        configSettings.MinimumFetchInternalInMilliseconds = 0;
        configSettings.FetchTimeoutInMilliseconds = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        configSettings.MinimumFetchInternalInMilliseconds = 900000;
        configSettings.FetchTimeoutInMilliseconds = 12000;
    }

    remoteConfig.SetConfigSettingsAsync(configSettings).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        //Set Default Config Values
        remoteConfig.SetDefaultsAsync(configDefaults).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            remoteConfig.FetchAndActivateAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
            {
                var info = remoteConfig.Info;
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Fetch canceled.");

                }
                else if (task.IsFaulted)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Fetch encountered an error.");

                }
                else if (task.IsCompletedSuccessfully)
                {
                    Debug.Log(String.Format("Remote data loaded and ready (last fetch time {0}).", info.FetchTime));
                }

                switch (info.LastFetchStatus)
                {
                    case LastFetchStatus.Failure:
                        switch (info.LastFetchFailureReason)
                        {
                            case FetchFailureReason.Error:
                                Debug.Log("Fetch failed for unknown reason");
                                break;
                            case FetchFailureReason.Throttled:
                                Debug.Log("Fetch throttled until " + info.ThrottledEndTime);
                                break;
                        }
                        break;
                    case LastFetchStatus.Pending:
                        Debug.Log("Latest Fetch call still pending.");
                        break;
                }

                IDictionary<string, ConfigValue> values = remoteConfig.AllValues;
                Debug.Log("Fetching firebase remote config data successful.");
                OnDataFetched?.Invoke(values);

            });

        });
    });

    }
```

It works perfectly when Unity editor connects to Internet. However, when I test the offline mode of my game on the Unity Editor, all the default config values are loaded perfectly but remote config SDK throws an exception like this:

> fetching failure: http code 0
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
> Firebase.Platform.FirebaseLogger:LogMessage (Firebase.Platform.PlatformLogLevel,string)
> Firebase.LogUtil:LogMessage (Firebase.LogLevel,string)
> Firebase.LogUtil:LogMessageFromCallback (Firebase.LogLevel,string)
> Firebase.AppUtil:PollCallbacks ()
> Firebase.Platform.FirebaseAppUtils:PollCallbacks ()
> Firebase.Platform.FirebaseHandler:Update ()
> Firebase.Platform.FirebaseMonoBehaviour:Update ()

I try to catch this exception and continue loading the game, because default config values are loaded perfectly. However I couldn't catch the exception, it throws anyway. And Editor only logged "task.IsFaulted" condition. How can I catch this exception or how should I handle this error when firebase offline?

Comment: Even though I updated the firebase sdk version from 9.5.0 to 10.3.0 this issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

We have struggled with Firebase Remote Config for a while. Recently we built a game on an alternative remote config platform, and have been happy with it. Developed by ex-game engineers. There is a nice Unity SDK.

Unity SDK Docs: https://docs.getjoystick.com/sdk-joystick-unity/

Easy to use (and team is responsive on Discord with troubleshooting)

```
using JoystickRemoteConfig;
using UnityEngine;


public class FetchContent : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RequestContentDefinition requestContentDefinition;
    private void Start()
    {
        Joystick.FetchConfigContent(requestContentDefinition, OnContentFetchComplete);
    }

    private void OnContentFetchComplete(bool success, string response)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            Debug.Log("Content Fetch Successful: " + response);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Content Fetch Failed: " + response);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer doesn't address the question that OP has. It provides an alternative SDK which changes the whole setup of the app.